# How to forbid DHCP-server to lease specific IP address on Mikrotik's routerOS?

Tags: dhcp, mikrotik, routeros

My Mikrotik router is running a DHCP server in /24 network, I would like to prohibit it to lease some IP addresses (I would like to use them statically on a couple of devices). Are there any ways to do it?

Comment: Usually router devices allow to specify the range of addresses assigned by DHCP.

Comment: That in not quite what I meant unfortuantly. The idea was to exclude several addresses form the ip range to assign.

Comment: You can assign those static addresses from outside the DHCP range.

Comment: Setting of range did the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the task as it was suggested in the comments: by creating a default-dhcp address pool. The "Pool" section could be found via Winbox software: IP -> Pool submenu.

Answer (score 1):

1. you can make several pools and use next-pool to exclude some addresses
2. make static lease for this ip addres to nonexistent mac adress